# Logger files running out of memory in production environment

Tags: c

I am using the `freopen` function of the C programming language to track

1. functions executed
2. warning messages
3. errors encountered

by routing all `stderr` messages to the designated text file. This worked fine in a testbed environment. However in production we encountered an out of memory exception for the log file opened with `freopen()`and the server is getting crashed. I need your help in solving this problem.

Comment: You probably mean `freopen`; but I don't understand your question. Show more code.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your logging code isn't leaking resources.

The `freopen()` function which I assume you're talking about, allocates memory to hold the `FILE` structure, and very probably additional space for e.g. buffering the I/O.

When you're done with the file, unless the process is about to terminate, you must call `fclose()` on the pointer returned by `freopen()`.

Of course, there might be any number of other resource-leaks in your code. It's hard to do this without seeing the code.

Comment: There is no memory leak within application profiled with C/C++ memory validator.This is causing only due to large number of print statements getting logged to the file.Is there any parameter do I need to set like [ MAX file size]